# weird intervals in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, timestamp, intervals

I am working with postgresql and when i want to calcalute the average of some      intervals between
two timestamps.    The intervals are correct but I get something like "235 days    29:28:02.642857"
I find it strange that it says 235 days and 29 hours instead of 236 days and 5 hours.

Comment: Are you sure you don't multiply it with a number? Some intervals can be tricky, f.ex. `set timezone to 'Europe/London'; select timestamptz '2015-10-26' - timestamptz '2015-10-25';` but I see no other reason to an average interval should produce 29+ hours (above the days). Anyway, you could use [justify_hours()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) to justify the result's hours.

Comment: thank you, when i use justify_hours it gives the excepted result. the timestamps i use are for example "2012-05-12 00:06:01+00" (type: timestamp with time zone)

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @pozs, you can use justify_hours(interval) to get them converted properly. If you want to convert the days to months, you may use justify_days(interval). If you want to do both at once, do justify_interval(interval)